# How do I get to use Work Order Status Object in FSL?

Tags: field-service-lightning, work-order-status

I have got FSL enabled in of my Sandboxes and I would like to explore and use "[Work Order Status and Work Order Line Status](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_standard_objects.htm&type=5)" objects. However, I don't seem to find these in the environment. Would like to know if these objects are something like where they could only be referenced or how does these objects work?

Comment: You could raise a case to Salesforce support team